# How change date format on date field drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, form-api

I need help to change the date format on the date field on a specific date field as shown below from the default format which is dd/mm/yyy to d-m-Y

```
$form['availability']['check_in_date'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#title' => $this->t('Check In Date'),
        '#date_date_format' => 'dd-mm-yy',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => $this->t('Please enter your check in date'),
        '#default_value' => (isset($customer_data->check_in_date)) ? $customer_data->check_in_date : '',
        '#attributes' => array('data-drupal-date-format' => "dd-mm-yy", 'type'=> 'date', 'min'=> '-1 day', 'max' => '+12 months'),
    );
```

I have tried the recommended way of adding the date field to form as shown from this [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Date.php/class/Date/8.2.x)

I even tried the suggestions below as part of the comment on the page event with this suggestion [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2646454)

All seems not to work, any ideas. thanks.

Comment: Change `'#date_date_format' => 'dd-mm-yy',` too `'#date_date_format' => 'd-m-Y',` ?

Comment: tried that before and even now seems not to work at all, keeps going back to default, maybe i am missing something or something.

Comment: Did you change `data-drupal-date-format` aswell?

Comment: Changed only #date_date_format first time and changed did not work, then changed #date_date_format and #data-drupal-date-format still did not work.

Comment: Did you clear or rebuild Drupal's cache ?

Comment: I did but severally but to no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I have tried many things but not working so i have just created the field as textfield and added the javascript datepicker to achieve the same result without breaking the drupal process and I am able to achieve the result i wanted.

Based on this I assume it is a bug in drupal 8 until it is fixed and a better workaround is provided for developers to be able to specify the format they want.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, by using hook_form_alter and changing the form field elements

```
$form["field_date_of_birth"]["widget"][0]['value']['#attributes']['data-drupal-date-format'] = ['d/m/Y'];
$form["field_date_of_birth"]["widget"][0]['value']['#date_date_format'] = 'd/m/Y';
$form["field_date_of_birth"]["widget"][0]['value']['#date_date_element'] = 'text';
$form["field_date_of_birth"]["widget"][0]['value']['#attributes']['title'] = t('Enter a valid date - e.g. @format', [
    '@format' => (new \DateTime())->format('d/m/Y'),
  ]);
```